# Novel with solar sail technology and gorilla-like aliens

Tags: story-identification, novel

This book had solar sail technology and gorilla-like aliens with one strong muscular arm and one weak arm.

Comment: Hi there. If you can, please take a look at [these guidelines](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/98028), see if they trigger any more memories you could [edit] in. For instance, when would this have been published?

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/167723/looking-for-book-contact-with-aliens-five-different-races-mismatched-claws-b

Answer (score 12):

"Mote In God's Eye" by Larry Niven and Jerry Pournelle.
What do I win? :)

Comment: For now, an upvote; and probably more if you improve your answer with an [edit] to explain how it matches what Lyn remembered, with your summary or quotes for instance :)

Comment: The Moties have one strong arm on one side and two weaker arms on the other side.  They also aren't described as "gorilla-like."

Comment: There were a large variety of Moties in different classes iirc, so some of them might have been described that way.

Comment: Thanks for all comments under my brief answer. Wasn't signed up and logged in, so am forced to post as an answer.
No, Moties aren't described as "gorilla-like." I checked. Lyn, the original poster, clearly has an imperfect recollection of the novel, not remembering the title, etc. That is why the question was asked. I inferred from this imperfect recollection that:
1) Solar Sailing Technology is Crazy Eddie Probe from "Mote in God's Eye."
2) "Gorilla-like" aliens with one strong arm and one weak one is an imperfect recollection of Moties, which indeed had different subspecies/categories ...

Comment: ... (Engineers, Mediators, Warriors etc.), one strong arm and two smaller/weaker arms, and had soft fur with patches, which can form an image of a gorilla-like alien in mind's eye especially after a long time passed since reading the novel. Since those were the only clues to go on, my answer is a guess, but it fits. I don't have a better one.

Comment: On the gripping hand, I always thought that the third (lowest) hand was the strongest, and it was on the same side as one of the 2 manipulating hands.

Comment: No, the 2 small arms are on the same side. There's a line about the elbows nesting like Dixie cups.

Comment: The two smaller arms are in the same side.  The gripping hand is the hand on the powerful arm.

Comment: @MarkSpace You are the same person as Mark, right? If so, better log in as Mark next time. But tell me, how did you manage to write comments?

Comment: @MrLister a mod converted his answer from another account to a comment.